# Angular Material 2: How to set date without close mdMenu

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am using material 2's menu. 
How can I click one of the menu items without closing menu popup?

Here is [link](http://embed.plnkr.co/WoULkR/)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

1. add function app.component.ts

   `stopClickPropagate(event: any){
       event.stopPropagation();
   }`
2. using it in app.component.html e.g. in `p` tag

`<p style="padding: 0 10px; border: 1px solid red" (click)="stopClickPropagate($event)">{{dateType}}</p>`